# Android Jetpack Compose dimensions coding standards

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, standards

For the old XML layouts I always use the **dimen.xml** file to define almost all dimensions, paddings, margins, etc.

While learning Jetpack Compose I find that all repositories, examples, etc., hardcode all dimensions related values directly into the compose code, even though I am aware that there is the possibility to use the **dimensionResource** method to read it from an xml file.

What is the recommended way for Compose regarding this? to keep using dimen XML files, or to hardcode it into the actual compose code?

Comment: it's better to keep it in app theme file so actually you should avoid hardcoding values in composable functions using app theme references for it and your app theme should have all the resources like colors, typography, shapes etc. and also you can include dimens there as well

Comment: As far as I know, Google has no clear limitations and recommendations on this. Personally, I always create .kt files in the ui.theme directory.

Comment: @easy_breezy Do you have any link with examples about what you mean regarding using app theme references? I am very new in compose and still get lost.

Comment: @API_1024 here is a google lab https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-theming#3

Comment: In their internal courses and examples, they use the dimens.xml file. Which is also the path that I chose. More intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google's official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/resources#dimensions) mentions that resource dimensions can be used with compose using `dimensionResource()` like below:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(
            horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_horizontal),
            vertical = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_vertical),
         ),
)
```

I also prefer using them. I've seen a post on Medium where the writer suggested using kotlin classes and objects to store dimens and then using some formulas to calculate which class must be used based on the screen dimension. Still, personally, I don't suggest going that road. The dimens are already sufficient enough, both in stability and ease of use.